# Is there any programming-related blog website that i can read on my pocket pc?

Tags: blogging

i googled but didn't find any, anyone kindly tell me some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read all my RSS feeds (*most blogs have RSS feeds*) on my iPhone via [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader). It adapts the feed to be easy to read on my iPhone. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the [StackOverflow feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds)?  (Not really a blog but it would work)  :o)  It also may be a little easier to provide you an accurate answer if you specified what programming languages you were interested in.